# Ansible - got an unexpected keyword argument - check_invalid_arguments

Tags: python, azure, ansible

I'm getting error when trying to run `Azure VirtualMachine Extension` module in ansible. Error - `got an unexpected keyword argument`. Need help to resolve the issue.

```
  - name: create Azure vm extension to enable HTTPS WinRM listener
    azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension:
      name: "winrm-extension"
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      virtual_machine_name: "{{ item.invocation.module_args.tags.hostname }}"
      publisher: Microsoft.Compute
      virtual_machine_extension_type: CustomScriptExtension
      type_handler_version: 1.9
      settings: '{"commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -EncodedCommand {{winrm_enable_script}}"}'
      auto_upgrade_minor_version: true
    with_items: "{{ azure_nic.results }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.invocation.module_args.tags.hostname }}"
    register: azure_vm_ext
```

Error:

```
TASK [create Azure vm extension to enable HTTPS WinRM listener] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible/azure_ansible/azure_playbook.yaml:48
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297="` echo /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/ansible/.ansible/roles/azure.azure_modules/library/_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-2993sfin7blt/tmpl484jblk TO /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/ /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/home/ansible/azure_ansible/ansible/bin/python3 /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py", line 100, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py", line 92, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension', _modlib_path=modlib_path),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py", line 337, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py", line 333, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py", line 203, in __init__
  File "/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 268, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_invalid_arguments'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py\", line 100, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py\", line 92, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1635021345.7221916-3079-69569921370297/AnsiballZ__azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 207, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 97, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py\", line 87, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py\", line 337, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py\", line 333, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension.py\", line 203, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload_f9qb4nrk/ansible_azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 268, in __init__\nTypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check_invalid_arguments'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Comment: Without the version of ansible you are using, you place the burden upon the Internet for tracking down the source code for your setup. But, to my discredit, I actually did check 2.8.20, 2.9.27, and then that file is totally missing in 2.10 and higher, so my strong suspicion is that you're on some ancient version that didn't get any bugfixes

Comment: I'm using ansible [core 2.11.6]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by upgrading my Ansible version.
Originally had v2.9.6 and upgraded to v2.12.4.

Steps taken:

> Uninstall: `sudo apt remove ansible`
>
> Install using pip3: `pip3 install ansible`
>
> Install system-wide using apt: `sudo apt install ansible`
>
> Check version: `ansible --version`

(Commands where executed on Ubuntu srv 20.04LTS).

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar problem too, and resolved it by upgrading Ansible from 2.9.6 to 2.13.1 following your steps on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
`Error was a <class 'TypeError'>, original message: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date'"}`

I found it strange to use both `apt` and `pip3`, so I verified that `pip3` is enough:
`docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:20.04 bash` -> `apt update` -> `apt-get install ansible` -> `ansible --version # 2.9.2` -> `apt-get install python3-pip` -> `pip3 install --upgrade ansible` -> `ansible --version # 2.13.1`
```